# Accessing deep properties and methods of an object with using a path

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a code snippet that I have been using and works. It is used a lot in my application and I need to speed it up. Is there a faster better way of deep accessing objects using a string path. It needs to able to access properties and methods, see my examples below:

```
     function get(obj, path) {
        var paths = path.split('.'),
        curProp = obj;
        for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
            if (!curProp[paths[i]]) return 
            curProp = (typeof curProp[paths[i]] !== "function") ? curProp[paths[i]] : curProp[paths[i]]() ;
        }
        return curProp;
    }
```

The snippet gets the property via the path for the object passed

```
var obj = {contact:{name:"john"}};
console.log(get(obj, "contact.name"));
```

If the object has a method that returns an object it can return that too

```
var obj = {contact:function(){return {name:"john"}}};
console.log(get(obj, "contact.name"));
```

Comment: Perhaps this would do? `return path.split('.').reduce((a, k) => a !== undefined && (typeof a === 'function' ? a()[k] : a[k]), obj)`

Comment: I ran some tests on jsperf my code is slightly faster, which is suprising

Comment: A `for` loop is likely to be faster than `reduce`. Although, "faster" at this level of optimization often doesn't matter. I'd go with what you think reads better.

Comment: Typo in your question. The example calls `get("contact.name",obj)` have the arguments in the wrong order. You can not speed the function up unless you use some very hacky methods. Eg flatten the loop so it runs iterations inline, and use a unique function property to determine the function as typeof is slower eg `prop = curProp[paths[i]].call ?  curProp[paths[i]]() : curProp[paths[i]];` but the improvements are tiny at best.

Comment: @elclanrs the question is can my code be optimized. And I get the impression the answer is no. I have ran a js perf test of a solution using reduce and my code is slightly faster. I'm not looking for tiny improvements I'm merely asking is their a faster, more concise way of doing it, since the code was written, 5 years ago.

Comment: @Blindman67 fixed typo and yes I agree

Comment: How does it work with functions that has 1+ parameters?

Comment: There is another code snippet that walks code and passes arguments into methods. The code needs to be fast, speed is the important factor, not functionality. Think of it like a racing car, it can't take passengers and it dont take luggage. We need this to be the fastest it can be, but we need to walk methods. We know the methods we walk dont need arguments and if they do we use a slightly adapted function to do that as fast as we can. That's how we do it.

Comment: You should have added either [tag:performance] or "optimized for performance" in your question, because it's not quite obvious. One can optimize code for readability, performance, memory consumption, and so on. My answer is probably invalidated by that requirement. Also, I see [tag:functional-programming] used. Functional programming in most cases is not the best approach performance-wise...

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming), I'd use `.forEach()` instead of a `for` loop. It abstracts the iteration process.

---

`if (!curProp[paths[i]]) return` does not seem quite right to me, because it will work funny with **falsy** values. It's better to rely on `object.hasOwnProperty()`, or `Object.keys()` depending on the way you want it to work.

Example:

```
var obj = {};
obj["property1"] = 0;
obj["property2"] = "";

obj["property1"] ? obj["property1"] : "No property1 is available";
  // --> "No property1 is available", isn't right from the humans perspective noramally

obj["property2"] ? obj["property2"] : "No property2 is available";
  // --> "No property2 is available"
```

---

I think, it's always good to spell out the return value. In other words, `return undefined` is better than `return` in this function.

---

Slightly different variant:

```
function get(targetObject, targetPropertyPath) {
    const pathPartList = targetPropertyPath.split('.');
    let currentProperty = targetObject;

    pathPartList.forEach(pathPart => {
        if (!currentProperty.hasOwnProperty(pathPart)) return undefined;

        const property = currentProperty[pathPart];
        currentProperty = (typeof property !== 'function') ? property : property();
    });

    return currentProperty;
}
```

Comment: Runs slower, it seems the original code is fast, though maybe not politically correct for design. Thanks for pointing out the errors will look into this, and re-test.

Comment: Not in the title i agree but it is mentioned: "It is used a lot in my application and I need to speed it up"

Comment: You're right, I missed that part. My bad. Anyway, at least I pointed out the correctness issue which is more important. Reversed my vote...

Comment: Yes and you are right. I have modified the tags so it is clear. Sorry for any misunderstanding and thank you again for correcting this.

Comment: @MartinWebb it runs slower because of the `.forEach` it's definitely not as performant compared to a `for` loop.

Comment: Yes i agree a long hand for each is faster.